# Axios not retuning correct data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I have a React application, where I am fetching some data, from an endpoint, where I am expecting two different arrays as response.

When i go into the terminal, i see that, it says `Array(2)`, but when i open up the data tab it only displays one array.
[image]

This anybody know if this is a bug or if this is something wrong with my application.

I tried from two separate clients (postman and regular browser), where there was no issue at all, so I am a bit confused, to as why this is happening?

I have taken into account, that the requests are `async`.

Here is my full code.

```
    const [{data, loading, error}, refetch] = useAxios(fetchInvoiceData);


useEffect(() =>{
        if(!loading){
        const ids = data.encodedImage.map(entry => entry._id)
        console.log(ids)
        console.log(fetchMultipleLabelData(ids))
        setLoadingPages(true)
        axios.get(fetchMultipleLabelData(ids)).then(res =>{
            console.log(res)
            setLoadingPages(false)
            const categories = generateCategories(res.data);
            const initialState = generateInitialState(res.data);
            setCategories(categories)
            console.log(categories)
            setGlobalState(initialState)
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.error(err)
        })
        } 
    }, [loading])
```

I have tried making it conditional by using a `loading` state to 'wait' with doing the http request.

Furthermore, since it gives a response, i assume, that it would return the full data???

EDIT:

i have no tried `Stringify`ing the json, and logging out the regular output aswell with the following result

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))
        console.log(res.data)
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible that you're console.logging it, but the SAME OBJECT is later changed to have only 1 before you inspect it in the console. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` to see if the json content has 2 or 1 in the array

Comment: @TKoL I have made an edit, showing your solution

Comment: It's not exactly easy to tell from that screenshot if you have the result you're expecting.